# REST API and Corda Security issues

Tags: corda

Does Corda have some best practice pattern how to organize security access with DAAPs. For example, REST API uses Corda node like a storage for accounts data, hashes of passwords etc. On the REST API side into the property file, we can hold settings for connection to the Corda node. Is it OK solution? Any best practice for it?

Answer (score 0):

You should secure the RPC connection to the node by following the instructions here: https://docs.corda.net/clientrpc.html#rpc-security-management.

You can also configure the RPC server via the `node.conf` file, as documented here: https://docs.corda.net/corda-configuration-file.html.